# How to add SSH key to GitLab via API

Tags: python, git, gitlab

The documentation has a section Add SSH Key.
We do it as described in the documentation

```
url_keys = f"https://gitlab.com/api/v4/user/keys"
response = requests.post(url_keys, data={ "title": "ABC",
  "key": "ssh-dss AAAAB3NzaC1kc3MAAACBA...",
  "expires_at": "2016-01-21T00:00:00.000Z"})
print(response.json())
```

Questions:

1. How does git know that I am me?
2. The answer is: {'message': '401 Unauthorized'}. How do I log in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send an API token alongside with the request:

```
response = requests.post(..., headers={"Private-Token": "your token here"})
```

This is both how GitLab knows it's you and how to fixe the 401 error.